# How to transfer parameters from JSP to Flex4?

Tags: jsp, apache-flex, flex4

I am developing a web application in which I need to transfer url parameter from JSP to Flex 4.

I think, I must use flashvars concept but I am not sure. Can anyone please help me out to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do it this way: JSP talks to java class that in turn talks to Flex. Let me know if you need more info

Comment: yes, can you please provide me an example. I am breaking my head since 2 days.

Comment: sure, can your java classes talk to flex? if so what method are you using?

Comment: Actually, am not using java classes. Am only using JSP and Flex. I would like to send "http://localhost:8080/Access/wyatt.mp3" from JSP to Flex and then need to assign it to url parameter.

Comment: have you looked at http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Building_Flex_Applications_with_JSPs-7746.html? This tells you how to talk between flex and JSP. I suspect your flex will have to initiate the process of fetching parameter from JSP.